# How to convert Nested _.each to synchronous method? Preferred use of Promises or Async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested, waterfall

```
var version = bible.version.toLowerCase();

fs.readFile('./texts/' + version + '.json', 'utf8', function getVersion(err, text) {
  var canon = JSON.parse(text);
  var writeCanon = '';

  fs.mkdir(bible.export + version + '/');

  _.each(canon, function (b, book) {
    var books = canon[book];
    var writeBooks = '';

    fs.mkdir(bible.export + version + '/' + book + '/');

    writeCanon += '<a alt="' + book + '" href="' + site.root + version + '/' + book + '/" id="' + book + '">' + book + '</a>\r\n';

    _.each(books, function (c, chapter) {
      var chapters = books[chapter];
      var writeChapters = '';

      fs.mkdir(bible.export + version + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/');

      writeBooks += '<a alt="' + book + ' ' + chapter + '" href="' + site.root + version + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/">' + chapter + '</a>\r\n';

      _.each(chapters, function (v, verse) {
        writeChapters += '<span id="' + verse + '">' + verse.sup() + ' ' + v + '</span>\r\n';

        fs.mkdir(bible.export + version + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/' + verse + '/');
        fs.writeFile(bible.export + version + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/' + verse + '/index.html', v);
      });

      fs.writeFile(bible.export + version + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/index.html', writeChapters);
    });

    fs.writeFile(bible.export + version + '/' + book + '/index.html', writeBooks);
  });

  fs.writeFile(bible.export + version + '/index.html', writeCanon);
});
```

I have this code I have been working on, and I was very pleased with the nested result, considering I'm just generating directories and files. The problem is that I need these to execute sequentially so that it doesn't try to create a file before the directory exists!

What I would like to do is use promises to do this, or if this is the wrong idea, then perhaps async.waterfall? I'm not sure how to push the values of _.each functions to the next one without them being nested. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON file?

Comment: This is the exact file I was working with: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/honza/bibles/master/ESV/ESV.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js provides synchronous versions of most of their methods. If you want everything to be executed in order (i.e., not with async callbacks), you can use those methods instead.

For `fs.mkdir` there is `fs.mkdirSync`, for `fs.readFile` there is `fs.readFileSync`, etc.

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks, it worked flawlessly.